# Selected project build from multi project repository using Bamboo

Tags: maven, svn, bamboo

Hi I have a SVN repo with around a 100 projects/apps (maven projects). All of them are totally independent and are build and and deployed in the same way. Using Bamboo can I (using one build plan) build only the the latest updated projects(from the last commit in the repo) or must have a separate build plan for each app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both ways are correct. It depends more on infrastructure setup. Do you deploy all 100 apps on same server and same directory? How similar are all 100 applications? What are future plans? Are you planning to move to Git in future? Are those 100 projects planning to be totally different in few months? If you don't foresee any change in next 4-5 months then you can have one build plan and pass app/project name as parameter.

Comment: Yes all apps are deployed on the same server, The apps are very similar. About moving to Git we have those plans, but for now it is in the future. The projects will not have any major changes in the future(different build process) . About "..pass app/project name as parameter" How one achieve that? My current Build plan has one job with 2 stages SVN checkout and maven install (that builds the jars), how to tell maven to build only the updated projects?  Note more then one project can be updated in one commit, so I'll need to build all updated projects and nothing else.

Comment: There are multiple ways. Easiest one I see is making separate commits for individual projects . Create one plan variable "ProjectName".While Running Bamboo plan , click on "Run as Customized " and then click on override variable. Now enter name of Project for variable and click on run. If you don't want to run manually, then with little scripting you can get name of project changed .